# anchor tag - can it be used at the end of the link

Tags: css, html, tags, anchor

I'm trying to redirect users to certain section within a page.

Normally you would put the anchor tag at the end. But because the marketing system we are using automatically inserts tracking link into href, I cannot seem to put the redirection anchor tag in the link.

For example:

```
href="www.yahoo.com/#collections"
```

When it goes through the marketing system, it becomes

```
href="www.yahoo.com/#collections?cid=tracking..."
```

I cannot edit this link manually unfortunately. I'm wondering if we can position the anchor tags in different parts of the link OR is there a way to add the redirection besides anchor tag?

Comment: The marketing system should be smart enough to understand the URL and separate query string from fragment.

Comment: How are you populating the anchor `href`s? And can you use JavaScript?

Comment: Have you actually tried this to see if it works? I don't think the query string makes a difference for in-page anchor links.

Comment: @Michael_B yes, the system automatically adds the tracking tag so it becomes e.g. "www.yahoo.com/#collections?cid=tracking..." and this does not redirect to the element (id) within the page

Comment: Yeah, it seems that you're right.

Comment: @rideron89 so there's unique id within the div tag which I can redirect using anchor tag. unfortunately, i can't use javascript as the link is from email html (hence js is not supported)

Comment: @PraveenKumar true but unfortunately, not at this stage. i hope to raise this issue during the next update session.

Comment: @Michael_B I know putting in anchor tag at the end of the link would work. but thats not possible in my circumstances as i cannot manually modify the link. when it goes through the marketing system we have here, it adds the tracking link at the end of the href link hence, cant add the anchor tag unless i put it in the href... but this would mean it would display as e,g, 'www.google.com/#collections?cid=tracking..."

Comment: If you don't have control over the page in question, I'm not sure there is anything you can do. The page you're linking to would have to parse the URL itself.

Comment: If you can't use JS, PHP or .htaccess to append fragment identifiers to the URL, then I would actually consider contacting the company / developers managing the tracking system. It's likely you're not the first to encounter this problem and they may have a workaround. Google seems to have one for Analytics ([link](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/57868/how-do-i-keep-the-hash-in-a-url-while-using-utm-query-strings-in-google-anal)).

Comment: Could you please specify how you are editing the html/link in your email? Are you providing the entire email html for the marketing system to parse and edit or just the url which the marketing system adds to an email template?

Answer (score 0):

Simply leave the href as is and add an onclick event:

```
onclick="window.location.href='#collections'; return false;"
```

It also might be possible just to use href="#collections" - if the marketing software is any good it should tell that's not a url. Conversely if you want to link to a specific page and anchor, use the onclick method above with the full url and #. If your marketing software even changes that in the onclick, try javascript string concatenation like:

```
onclick="window.location.href='www.yahoo' + '.com' + '#collections'; return false;"
```

```css
.test
{
  height:650px; 
  width: 450px;
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
<a href="www.yahoo.com?cid=tracking" onclick="window.location.href='#test4'; return false;">LINK WITH tracking</a>
<div class="test" style="background:red">
 <a name="test1"></a>
 TEST
</div>
<div class="test" style="background:lightblue">
 <a name="test2"></a>
 222222222222222 sadsad fsadf 
</div>
<div class="test" style="background:pink">
 <a name="test3"></a>
 3333333 3333 333a sd fasdf asdf
</div>
<div class="test" style="background:yellow">
 <a name="test4"></a>
 444444 4444 4444444444 sadf sadf
</div>
<div class="test" style="background:grey">
 <a name="test5"></a>
 555555 sadf sadf
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: This looked promising, but I OP just said the link is in an email so he can't JS.